# Depth First Directory Traversing resulting in Segmentation Fault in C

Tags: c, unix, directory, depth-first-search

I am writing a code to traverse through the directory using `depth first` algorithm. The problem is the program is not displaying anything and gives `Segmentation Fault error`. I tried to debug it but it was worthless as I am still learning stuff. So now I need the help of experts. Here is the code:

```
void func(char path[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    char buf[255];

    scanf("%s",buf);
    func(buf);
    return 0;
}

void func(char path[]) {
    DIR *dirp;
    struct stat states;
    struct dirent *direntp;
    printf("Inside\n");
    dirp=opendir(path);
    stat(path, &states);

    while ((direntp=readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
        if (S_ISDIR(states.st_mode)) {
            printf("Calling Func\n");
            func(direntp->d_name);
            chdir("..");
        } else if (!S_ISDIR(states.st_mode)) {
            printf("  %s\n", direntp->d_name);
        } else if (!strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(direntp->d_name, "..")) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return ;
}
```

Comment: The `if(!S_ISDIR)` and `if(S_ISDIR)` parts should be exchanged (not to mention that `if (cond) { } else if (!cond)` is redundant as heck...)

Comment: Also please indent properly.

Comment: If a directory is passed to `func()`: Could it be you are missing to `chdir()` into this directoy?

Comment: Compile your code using `-Wall -g`, fix it until there are no more warnings. If it segfaults use `gdb `to see where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside func, in front of the while, put that:

```
dirp=opendir (path);
if (!dirp)
  return;
```

and, btw, its `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: Sorry the main argument is a typo

Comment: But still it is not displaying any files name.

Comment: Hmm, you are examining states, which is set by stat of the path thrown into func, and is never updated inside the while. Instead you should examine direntp, which loops thru all the entries.

Comment: I already tried to use `direntp->d_type` in place of `states.st_mode`, but still it is not displaying file names.

Comment: if you put a  `printf("  %s %d\n",direntp->d_name, direntp->d_type);` as first statement in your while, you see the d_type beeing 4 for dirs or 8 for files.

Comment: But I want to display the names of the files. How can I do that?

Comment: (direntp->d_type & DT_DIR) is != 0, if direntp points to a directory entry. if it's 0, then its not a dir, e.g. file or link. So instead of writing `if(S_ISDIR(states.st_mode))` you write `if (direntp->d_type & DT_DIR)` (and of course change/remove the other `S_ISDIR`-occurences

Comment: this gave me a little success but the output is wrong.. it is repeatedly displaying some files and also going to the parent directory of the mentioned directory, which It should not do

Comment: Hihi. This comes from the fact that you treat . and .. special, but not in the correct way. This should be the first check, not the last. If its . or .., just continue, do nothing else. Instead, your current impl first goes down into . or .., and then continues (which makes no sense)

Answer (score 0):

For debugging printing, print to `stderr`; it is line buffered, so it appears more reliably.

Your function, in outline, is:

```
void func(char path[])
{
    DIR *dirp;
    struct stat states;
    struct dirent *direntp;
    printf("Inside\n");
    dirp=opendir(path);
    stat(path,&states);

    while ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
    {
        if (S_ISDIR(states.st_mode))
        {
            printf("Calling Func\n");
            func(direntp->d_name);
            chdir("..");
        }
        else if (!S_ISDIR(states.st_mode))
        {
            printf("  %s\n",direntp->d_name);
        }
        else if (!strcmp(direntp->d_name,".") || !strcmp(direntp->d_name,".."))
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

The `chdir("..")` is unwise; you've neither done a `chdir()` to the relevant directory nor ensured that the directory is a direct sub-directory of the current directory, which means this code is going to go haywire...if it ever gets to that bit.

You do `stat(path, &states);` but do not check that it worked.

You do `dirp = opendir(path);` but do not check that it worked.

You don't do `stat()` on each entry; you continually use the initial stat from `path`.  This is probably a directory when you test, so you then call the function recursively, which will be reading `.`, which is a directory, and you would probably just end up running out of stack if you didn't run out of `DIR` pointers first.

Your tests in the loop are wrongly sequenced, even if you arranged to `stat()` the file — which is a non-trivial operation because the name you just read has to be appended to the path of the directory to form the correct file name.  Your code is:

```
if (is a directory)
else if (is not a directory)
else if (name is . or ..)
else ...missing...
```

First, the `if` and the following `else if` covers all options, so the name test and final (non-existent) `else` would never be executed.  You probably need the name test first (pseudo-code):

```
if (name is a "." or "..")
    print "Skipping";
else if (name is a directory)
{
    create "path/name" as string;
    recurse with "path/name";
}
else
    print "Skipping non-directory";
```

Note that this always prints something in every iteration.  That's very important while you're debugging.  You don't want the code to be quiet when it does something you aren't expecting.

Note that you do not call `closedir()`; this means you will run out of directory descriptors, getting a NULL value in `dirp` which crashes when you use it.

Note that the pseudo-code does not include any `chdir()` operations.  Be very, very, very cautious about using them.  Understand the use of `fchdir()`.

Read up on [`ftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftw.html) and [`nftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html); there are notes about the complications that those functions face.